# Como ler um array de arrays e salvar cada array[ ] em uma variável diferente para executar função com barplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como posso fazer para ler esse array de arrays:

```
[45 32 56 57 44 21 36 35 39 23 24 27 25 26 31 28 29 30 20 22 18  8 19  1
 33  2  3  4  0  6  7  9 17 10 11 12 49 55 13 14 15 16 52 46 43 34 41 37
 40  5 54 51 53 47 38 42 50 48] [50 34 46 45 48 24 27 28 26 43 32 19 10 25 18 12 20 13  7 15 17  9  8 14
 22 21  4  3  5 16  1  6  0 11  2 29 47 52 55 57 54 56 38 35 31 23 37 53
 33 42 36 49 51 44 39 41 30 40] [54 29 40 42 53 23 31 34 37 39 38 17 19 22 12 10 11  3  6 13 15  8 14 16
 25 27  4  5 21  0  1 18  9  7  2 32 28 46 48 57 56 55 20 44 33 26 41 52
 24 45 43 50 51 49 35 30 47 36] [57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34
 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10
  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0]
```

Salvar cada *array* em uma variável diferente: `ranks1`, `ranks2`, `ranks3`, `ranks4`, `ranks5` e conseguir executar estas funções:

Uma que está na main:

```
frk.plot_ranks(ranks1, ranks2, ranks3, ranks4, ranks5, ... )
```

E essa outra que funciona para plotar os gráficos em outro script:

```
def plot_ranks(bars1, bars2, bars3, bars4, bars5, features_train, title, RESULT_PATH='Results'):

    df = pd.DataFrame({'LA': bars1, 'DT': bars2, 'RF': bars3, 'PCA': bars4, 'ARD': bars5})
    index = X
    df.index = index
    ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True)

    plt.show()
```

O que acontece é que se por exemplo não tem uma destas variáveis, digamos que `bars5` não esteja no *array* a função `plot_ranks()` não executa e dá erro. Como eu posso separar este *array* de *arrays* nestas variáveis: `ranks1`, `ranks2`, `ranks3`, `ranks4`, `ranks5` (da função que está na main) e mesmo na ausência de uma delas estas funções possam ser executadas para que o gráfico seja plotado e não dê erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que sua *array* bidimensional de entrada seja algo como:

```
entrada = [
    [45,32,56,57,44,21,36,35,39,23,24,27,25,26,31,28,29,30,20,22,18,8,19,1,33,2,3,4,0,6,7,9,17,10,11,12,49,55,13,14,15,16,52,46,43,34,41,37,40,5,54,51,53,47,38,42,50,48],
    [50,34,46,45,48,24,27,28,26,43,32,19,10,25,18,12,20,13,7,15,17,9,8,14,22,21,4,3,5,16,1,6,0,11,2,29,47,52,55,57,54,56,38,35,31,23,37,53,33,42,36,49,51,44,39,41,30,40],
    [54,29,40,42,53,23,31,34,37,39,38,17,19,22,12,10,11,3,6,13,15,8,14,16,25,27,4,5,21,0,1,18,9,7,2,32,28,46,48,57,56,55,20,44,33,26,41,52,24,45,43,50,51,49,35,30,47,36],
    [57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
]
```

Você pode convertê-la em um dicionário, criando uma chave para cada elemento da lista.

```
data = {
    'rank1': entrada[0],
    'rank2': entrada[1],
    'rank3': entrada[2],
    'rank4': entrada[3],
}
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
data = {f'rank{i}' : e for i, e in enumerate(entrada,1)}
```

Uma vez com o dicionário criado, você será capaz de criar um `DataFrame` a partir dele:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Colocando tudo junto:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

entrada = [
    [45,32,56,57,44,21,36,35,39,23,24,27,25,26,31,28,29,30,20,22,18,8,19,1,33,2,3,4,0,6,7,9,17,10,11,12,49,55,13,14,15,16,52,46,43,34,41,37,40,5,54,51,53,47,38,42,50,48],
    [50,34,46,45,48,24,27,28,26,43,32,19,10,25,18,12,20,13,7,15,17,9,8,14,22,21,4,3,5,16,1,6,0,11,2,29,47,52,55,57,54,56,38,35,31,23,37,53,33,42,36,49,51,44,39,41,30,40],
    [54,29,40,42,53,23,31,34,37,39,38,17,19,22,12,10,11,3,6,13,15,8,14,16,25,27,4,5,21,0,1,18,9,7,2,32,28,46,48,57,56,55,20,44,33,26,41,52,24,45,43,50,51,49,35,30,47,36],
    [57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
]

data = {f'rank{i}' : e for i, e in enumerate(entrada,1)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data);
df.plot.bar(stacked=True);
plot.show(block=True);
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]